# rank and dimension of null space and range of matrix over complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How would I find the rank of this matrix over the field of complex numbers?  I also want to find the basis of the range and the basis of the null space?  Is it a standard row reducing process or is there another way to find the rank and other information without the trouble of row reducing.

Thanks in advance

> \begin{equation}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1&1-i&1\\
> i-1-1&1&1+2i\\
> i+1&2&1+i\\
> 0&i&-1\\
> \end{pmatrix}
> \end{equation}

Comment: Just by standard row reduction/Gaussian elimination, just as you would do with a real matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you find easier, an alternative would be to compute the Gram matrix $\mathbf A^{\rm H} \mathbf A$, which has the same rank as $\mathbf A$. In your case, to compute it all you need is the squared norms of your three column vectors (8, 8, 9) and their mutual inner products ($1-4i$, $3-5i$, $4+6i$).

This gives the Gram matrix as $$\mathbf A^{\rm H} \mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix} 8 & 1-4i & 3-5i \\ 1+4i & 8 & 4+6i \\ 3+5i & 4-6i & 9 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Direct computation gives ${\rm det}(\mathbf A^{\rm H} \mathbf A) = 3 > 0$ and hence $\mathbf A$ has rank 3. Its columns are therefore already a basis for its range. Then again, if you also need a basis for its row space, you might be better of just row-reducing the original $\mathbf A$ instead of going through its Gram...